# SSRS if condition for time

Tags: sql, datetime, reporting-services

I'm trying to make an expression that will show only date if the time is 12 a.m. , and will show date/time if the time is anything but 12 a.m.

I'm new to `SSRS`, so I'm not exactly sure how to go about this. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I would recommend that you at least try something and post it. You are more likely to get help (and learn) that way.

Comment: I'm just not sure how to target PART of the datetime tag. which is pretty much the first part. I see lots of examples to target date but none on time within the datetime.

Comment: Are you trying to do this is t-sql if so which version (sql server) or are you looking for a solution in SSRS (vba)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this will help from an SSRS perspective. Enter this expression in your text box.

```
=IIF( TimeValue(Fields!DateField.Value) = "12:00:00 AM", 
      FORMAT(Fields!DateField.Value, "MM/dd/yyyy"), 
      Fields!DateField.Value)
```

This is assuming you have correct datatypes in place.

Answer (score 0):

The solution involves casting the datetime value as time into another variable and checking just that part. Running the solution below as-is will produce a "00:00:00" time value. If you comment out the first line and un-comment the 2nd line, the getdate() function will return a specific time value and you will see the whole DATETIME string.

```
DECLARE @v_datetime DATETIME = '2018-04-30'   --- no time
--DECLARE @v_datetime DATETIME = GETDATE()    --- includes time
DECLARE @v_time TIME = CAST(@v_datetime AS TIME)

IF @v_time = '00:00:00' BEGIN
    SELECT CAST(@v_datetime AS DATE) Result
END
ELSE BEGIN 
    SELECT @v_datetime Result
END
```

Comment: Good to hear Nathan. Can you please mark the answer as accepted? It will help people who see this post in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the format field of the relevant text box enter the following code with DATEFIELD replaced by the name of your field:

```
=Switch(Hour(Fields!DATEFIELD.Value)=cint(0) And Minute(Fields!DATEFIELD.Value)=cint(0) And Second(Fields!DATEFIELD.Value)=cint(0),"dd/MM/yyyy",
True,"dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```