# SSRS Time expression filter not working with Parameter boolean value

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

Background:

Trying to achieve a filter in dataset, if the user selects Day shift from the parameter, any data entry between 06:00:00 and 18:00:00 is filter in the report. Furthermore, any data entry between 18:00:00 and 06:00:00 is reflect in the report for Night shift

Process:

I have got a parameter with 2 Boolean values "True" and "False". I have labeled those values as "Day shift" and "Night shift" in the available value Parameter window option. Default value is true.

Converting datetime to time, in the dataset query

```
SELECT
CONVERT(time, SWITCHOFFSET(CONVERT(datetimeoffset, LastModified),DATENAME(TzOffset, SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()))) as ShiftTime
FROM table abc
```

Filter expression:`=Fields!ShiftTime.Value`

Operator: `in`

Value: `=IIf(  ( TimeValue(Fields!ShiftTime.Value) >= "06:00:00" And TimeValue(Fields!ShiftTime.Value) <= "18:00:00" ) , Parameters!ShiftType.Value(0), Parameters!ShiftType.Value(1) )`

> Problem:  [BC30516] Overload resolution failed because no accessible
> 'IIf' accepts this number of arguments

Not sure which part I am going wrong with, I am thinking it is the datatype but unsure.

[Solution which I built on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106655/ssrs-if-condition-for-time)

Comment: @DaleK I saw an example somewhere in Stakoverflow, it was ticked as correct. So I thought might give it a try even though it wasn't making sense. Although, that didn't really change the problem statement.

Comment: @DaleK I have tested my approach in different ways. Unfortunately, SSRS doesn't provide the granular error so it is difficult to debug. Anyways, I am here with a problem. I don't expect someone to do the work for me. Although, would appreciate if someone more knowledgeable could indicate where is the problem.

Comment: @DaleK so dataset query output is something like 06:00:00.0000000. How do I compare it in the iif statement filter? I have tried to compare it without TimeValue. Although, no difference in error.

Comment: @DaleK unfortunately, I have closed the link for that solution. The solution was similar to what I have got. Although it was comparing with an '=' operator. I don't know if you are trying to help or mocking my question. If you don't have anything to offer, please don't waste your and my time. Thanks.

Comment: I am trying to help... if you found the link once you can find it again. And **correct** your tags. You need to consider that when someone else is trying to assist you they don't have any of the background information. Therefore you need to make your question as clear as possible.

Comment: @DaleK sorry mate, it is frustrating. Not my area of work. I will find the link shortly.

Comment: @DaleK found it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50106655/ssrs-if-condition-for-time

Comment: @DaleK if you could help me understand this, the value from the dataset query is a string, that needs to be converted in the filter expression? what should it be converted as for it to support a value of "06:00:00" so that the comparison could work?

Comment: According to your SQL query you provided, the value in your dataset is a `TIME` value, not a string value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what report designer you are using, but using the Report Designer extension for Visual Studio gives me very different errors.

And it gives errors both in the output window, and the expression window when building it.

Firstly to debug this, add it as a column to your report before you try and implement it as a filter.

Then check the relevant documentation for the function. It turns out the [`TimeValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/timevalue-function) function takes a string, not a DateTime, and returns a datetime.

Then, you can't access the available parameter values from the parameter, you can only access the selected parameter values. So instead of `Parameters!ShiftType.Value(0)` (which has a red line under it) you should just have `true` (or `false` depending on which way around your logic is) i.e. the value of the parameter.

Finally, I don't know what implicit conversion SSRS does from strings to a time, so I would do an explicit time compare instead of a string compare. Given we know that TimeValue returns a DateTime with the minimum date value and the time component we can compute the required limites for day/night shift.

The following is what worked for me:

```
=IIf(TimeValue(Fields!ShiftTime.Value.ToString()) >= DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(6) And TimeValue(Fields!ShiftTime.Value.ToString()) <= DateTime.MinValue.AddHours(18), true, false)
```

And actually re-visiting it, thats way too convoluted, you are already returning a `time` value which we can compare directly as

```
=IIf(Fields!ShiftTime.Value >= new TimeSpan(6,0,0) And Fields!ShiftTime.Value <= new TimeSpan(18,0,0), true, false)
```

And then your filter should be:

Filter expression: {as shown above}

Operator: =

Value: =Parameters!ShiftType.Value

Note: when you say "between" I don't know whether the intention is to include both 6am and 6pm within the day shift window, but I haven't modified your logic in that regard.

Comment: both mentioned method works. Although, replacing true and false with the parameter. Is throwing the failed to evaluate the filtervalues of the dataset.

Comment: "Although, replacing true and false with the parameter. Is throwing" I don't understand this? But you don't want to replace them - in fact you can't replace.

Comment: sorry, yeah got lost with Boolean, It works. Appreciate the help!